# What does ‘we’re met’ mean?

Tags: meaning

I want to know what ‘We’re met.’ means.
Does this have a different meaning of ‘We meet’?
I want to know in which case do English speakers use that kind of sentence.

Comment: Why do you think English speakers say this at all?

Comment: See https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/we-are-met-here.1052168/

Comment: Thank you so much :) @Kate Bunting